# What is the Difference between Bottom-up and Top down methods in splay tree?

Tags: c, data-structures, splay-tree

I have read about Splay tree and I found,there are two methods for constructing the splay tree. They are

1. Bottom-up
2. Top-down

So I need to know What is the difference between the two methods and their working ?

Answer (score 2):

A **top-down splay tree**: performs rotations on the initial access path. Thus a top-down splay tree node does not need a parent link. The splay operation finishes as soon as the search does. That means the overhead for operations of a top-down splay tree is of a relatively small amount.

**Bottom-up splay tree**: requires a traversal from the root down the tree and then a bottom-up traversal to implement the splaying step, so a bottom-up splay tree implementation looks similar to that of an AVL tree. Besides, it needs a parent link or a stack to store the search path.

An implementation of a top-down splay tree can be found in the data structure [book](http://www.uoitc.edu.iq/images/documents/informatics-institute/Competitive_exam/DataStructures.pdf) (Chapter 12) written by Weiss.

Answer (score 0):

The methods define how you use splaying when searching:

**Bottom-up:** you search the tree and rotate at the same iteration

**Top-down:** you first search and at another iteration you rotate

you can read [Splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree)

This ideas hold to the creation also, when using the top down you insert the key as if it was a binary serach tree and than move it to the head in another iteration.

Comment: huh I thought bottom-up is two passes (first traverse tree as a BST then rotate one node backward until it becomes the root) and top-down is one pass (rotate inplace while traversing the tree)